# How do I make Eclipse clean specific files when autogenerating make files

Tags: eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I use Eclipse CDT to auto generate make files. Now I've added some make flags to create coverage information which results in *.gcno files being created when building. When cleaning my project only *.d and *.o files are removed. What I wonder is how to extend clean to also remove *.gcno files while still letting Eclipse auto generate my make files.

Cheers,
Ceqvi

Comment: I've made a sort of fix by creating a makefile.defs and setting "CPP_DEPS += ./*/*.gcno" in that file. Makefile.defs is automatically included in the Eclipse generated makefile and the clean target includes the CPP_DEPS variable causing the .gcno files to be cleaned. Not the perfect solution since .gcno files aren't exactly dependency-files, I'd like to add another variable (e.g. COVERAGE) to the clean target and be able to set that variable, but have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and you gave me an idea that works much better:

In *Makefile.targets*:

```
clean: clean-gcov

clean-gcov:
    -$(RM) $(foreach subdir,$(SUBDIRS),$(wildcard $(subdir)/*.gcda) $(wildcard $(subdir)/*.gcno))
```

Running it:

```
$ make clean
rm -rf   src/Hello.gcda src/Hello.gcno
rm -rf  ./src/test/HelloTest.o ./src/Hello.o ./src/test/HelloTest.d ./src/Hello.d  test
```